Support of a function acting on an algebra?
Quick: for a measurable function $f$ its support on Euclidean space is clearly just the subset where $f$ does not vanish.
Now, let’s have $f$ acting on an finite Lie algebra, f.e. $\mathfrak{gl}$ as $f(G,M)=\sum_G U^\dagger M U$, for $U$ being unitary, $G$ is just a subset of the unitary group. How would I calculate the support of $f$ concretely? Are there references where I could look up how others did something similar?
It is of course an abuse of notations yes, but I hope you know what I mean. $f$ is acting on a subset of $\mathfrak{gl}$ therefore $f(G,M)$. Additionally, we know $M$, what I am looking for is somehow the support of a function regarding the subset $G$.
If you see this as not fitting the question, feel free to reformulate what I am actually looking for. I regarded my problem now from many different angles, now I’m trying it from a functional analysis standpoint.
